# Max amount of parallel value access

Tags: c#, parallel.for

When I limit the amount of threads for my parallel for to 6 or below, it works fine. Anything above 6, it says it can't read the object at the specified location. Is there was a certain amount of times you can initialize the same object at a time, or how can I fix the error it gives out? All the code works fine if the MaxDegreeOfParallelism is <=6

```
Parallel.For(4, erCnt/2 ,opt, a =>
{
    if (a % 2 == 0)
    {
        dynamic[] name = new dynamic[2], num = new dynamic[2], wage = new dynamic[2], dept = new dynamic[2];//, name1 = new dynamic[2], num1 = new dynamic[2], wage1 = new dynamic[2], dept1 = new dynamic[2];
        num[0] = (string)(empSheet.Cells[a, 1] as Excel.Range).Value2;
        name[0] = (string)(empSheet.Cells[a, 2] as Excel.Range).Value2 + "," + (string)(empSheet.Cells[a, 3] as Excel.Range).Value2;
        dept[0] = ((empSheet.Cells[a, 4] as Excel.Range).Value2);
        wage[0] = (empSheet.Cells[a, 5] as Excel.Range).Value2;
        num[1] = (string)(empSheet.Cells[a + 1, 1] as Excel.Range).Value2;
        name[1] = (string)(empSheet.Cells[a + 1, 2] as Excel.Range).Value2 + "," + (string)(empSheet.Cells[a + 1, 3] as Excel.Range).Value2;
        dept[1] = ((empSheet.Cells[a + 1, 4] as Excel.Range).Value2);
        wage[1] = (empSheet.Cells[a + 1, 5] as Excel.Range).Value2;
        employee.Add(name[0], dept[0]);
        employee.Add(name[0], wage[0]);
        employee.Add(name[0], num[0]);
        employee.Add(name[1], wage[1]);
        employee.Add(name[1], dept[1]);
        employee.Add(name[1], num[1]);
    }
});
```

Comment: This question is hard to answer without code.

Comment: You probably just have some race condition which only becomes apparent if enough threads are running. You will need to share your code if you want people to help you find the bug. Try to post a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I just added the code that is causing a problem

Comment: What is employee? Is it thread-safe? Your Parallel.For could well have multiple threas accessing employee.Add() at the same time.

Comment: here is my definition for employee

    `public static MultiValueDictionary<string, dynamic> employee = new MultiValueDictionary<string, dynamic>();`